# How does behave linux buffer cache when an application is crashing down?

Tags: c++, linux, file-io, filesystems, io

Let's say I am using c++ files stream asynchronously. I mean never using std::flush nor std::endl. My application writes a lot of data to a file and abruptly crashes down.
Is the data remaining in the cache system flushed to the disk, or discarded (and lost)?

Comment: Ew. Recommend you switch to C for a few decades to familiarize yourself with the OS :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Complicating this problem is that there are multiple 'caches' in play.

C++ streams have their own internal buffering mechanism. Streams don't ask the OS to write to disk until either (a) you've sent enough data into the buffer that the streams library thinks the write wouldn't be wasted (b) you ask for a flush specifically (c) the stream is in line-buffering mode, and you've sent along the `endl`. Any data in these buffers are lost when the program crashes.

The OS will buffer writes to make best use of the limited amount of disk IO available. Writes will typically be flushed within five to thirty seconds; sooner if the programmer (or libraries) calls `fdatasync(2)` or `fsync(2)` or `sync(2)` (which asks for all dirty data to be flushed). Any data in the OS buffers are written to disk (eventually) when the program crashes, *lost* if the kernel crashes.

The hard drive will buffer writes to try to make the best use of its slow head, rotational latency, etc. Data arrives in this buffer when the OS flushes its caches. Data in these buffers are written to disk when the program crashes, will *probably* be written to disk if the kernel crashes, and *might* be written to disk if the power is suddenly removed from the drive. (Some have enough power to continue writing their buffers, typically this would take less than a second anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

The stuff in the library buffer (which you flush with std::flush or such) is lost, the data in the OS kernel buffers (which you can flush e.g. with fsync()) is not lost unless the OS itself crashes.