# Crash after write in linux

Tags: linux

What would happen if I were to use write() to write some data to a file on disk. But my application were to crash before flushing. Is it guaranteed that my data will get eventually flushed to disk if there is no system failure?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132343/how-does-behave-linux-buffer-cache-when-an-application-is-crashing-down).

Comment: @111111 If you're concerned about transactional integrity, you can't use `std::ofstream`, since it has no option which guaranteed disk synchronization.  Typically, you'll use `std::ostringstream` to construct a record (if the file is text oriented), and then output that in one atomic action using `write()`.

Comment: @111111 And RAII buys you nothing in the case of your process crashing (and even less if the system crashes, of course).

Comment: @JamesKanze which is why I said 'depending on what you mean by crash.'

Comment: I kind of feel my question was already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132343/how-does-behave-linux-buffer-cache-when-an-application-is-crashing-down

Comment: @111111 The two possible meanings are that the process crashes, and that the system crashes.  In neither case does RAII help.  (And the way he formulated his question makes it clear he was talking about the process crashing, not the system.)

Comment: @JamesKanze ok I removed my comment.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using `write` (and not `fwrite` or `std::ostream::write`),
then there is no in process buffering.  If there is no system failure,
then the data will, sooner or later (and generally fairly soon) be
written to disk.

If you're really concerned by data integrity, you can or in the flags
`O_DSYNC` and `O_SYNC` to the flags when you open the file.  If you do
this, you are guaranteed that the data is physically written to the disk
before the return from `write`.

Comment: [kernel.org docs](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/write.2.html) say this: "A successful return from write() does not make any guarantee that data has
       been committed to disk.  In fact, on some buggy implementations, it does not
       even guarantee that space has successfully been reserved for the data.  The
       only way to be sure is to call fsync(2) after you are done writing all your
       data."

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If `write` returns, the kernel has your data, if it ever hits platter is a different story. (also `fsync` may not help since disks have their own caches). The key here is `commited to disk` which can't be guaranteed

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Obviously, if the implementation is buggy, then you can't guarantee anything.  A return from `write()` guarantees that the OS has the data, and will "finish up" processing it regardless of what happens to your process.  If you use the flags I mention in `open`, then according to Posix, the system should not return from `write()` until full data integrity is guaranteed.  (In practice, this may not be possible on some file systems, particularly remotely mounted ones.)