# Writing to Linux pipe faster than file, but on a kernel level, why?

Tags: linux, pipe, kernel, ipc

I am looking at speed of writing to file vs a pipe.  Please look at this code, **which writes to a file handle unless there is a command line argument, otherwise it writes to a pipe:**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

using namespace std;


void do_write(int fd)
{
    const char* data = "Hello world!";
    int to_write = strlen(data), total_written = 0;
    
    int x = 0;
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    
    while (x < 50000)
    {       
        int written = 0;
        while (written != to_write)
        {
            written += write(fd, data + written, to_write - written);
        }
        total_written += written;
        ++x;
    }
    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto diff = end - start;
    
    cout << "Total bytes written: " <<  total_written << " in " << chrono::duration<double, milli>(diff).count() 
        << " milliseconds, " << endl;
}
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    //
    // Write to file if we have not specified any extra argument
    //
    
    if (argc == 1)
    {   
        {   
            int fd = open("test.txt", O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 0655);
            if (fd == -1) return -1;
            do_write(fd);
        }   
        
        return 0;
    }
    
    //
    // Otherwise, write to pipe
    //
    int the_pipe[2];
    if (pipe(the_pipe) == -1) return -1;
    
    pid_t child = fork();
    switch (child)
    {
    case -1:
        {
            return -1;
        }
    case 0:
        {
            char buf[128];
            int bytes_read = 0, total_read = 0;
            close(the_pipe[1]);
            while (true)
            {
                if ((bytes_read = read(the_pipe[0], buf, 128)) == 0)
                    break;
                total_read += bytes_read;
            }
            cout << "Child: Total bytes read: " << total_read << endl;
            break;
        }
    default:
        {
            close(the_pipe[0]);
            do_write(the_pipe[1]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my output:

```
$ time ./LinuxFlushTest pipe

Total bytes written: 600000 in 59.6544 milliseconds,

real    0m0.064s
user    0m0.020s
sys     0m0.040s
Child: Total bytes read: 600000

$ time ./LinuxFlushTest
Total bytes written: 600000 in 154.367 milliseconds,

real    0m0.159s
user    0m0.028s
sys     0m0.132s
```

You can see writing to the pipe is way faster than the file from both the `time` output and my C++ code timing.

Now, from what I know, when we call `write()` the data will be copied to a kernel buffer, at which point a `pdflush` style thread will actually flush it from the page cache to the underlying file.  **I am not forcing this flush in my code so there is no disk seeking delay.**

But what I don't know (and can't seem to find out: **and yes, I've looked at the kernel code but get lost in it, so no comments like "look at the code" please**) is what different happens when writing to a pipe: is it not just a block of memory in the kernel somewhere that the child can read from?  In that case, why is it so much faster than the basically identical process of writing to a file?

Answer (score 1):

> Now, from what I know, when we call `write()` the data will be copied
> to a kernel buffer, at which point a `pdflush` style thread will
> actually flush it from the page cache to the underlying file. **I am
> not forcing this flush in my code so there is no disk seeking delay.**

You seem to have some misconceptions there, including:

1. You do not have to explicitly do anything for the kernel to flush the written data to the underlying output device.  It may buffer some or even all of the data in memory for a time, at its discretion, but it is to be expected that the kernel will indeed write the data at some point even without explicit instruction from userspace.  This is likely to be influenced by the amount of data written, which appears in your case to be a moderately large 600000 bytes.
2. Disk seeking is not the only reason for disk I/O being (comparatively) slow.  Even I/O with a SSD is slower than memory-only data transfer.
3. Among other things, a standard file system is not simply a flat span of bytes.  Even without any moving parts, one still has to interact with the file system's data structures to figure out where to write, and to update it when you have written. It is usually desirable for that information to become visible to other processes promptly, so it is *not* normally deferred indefinitely.

> But what I don't know [...] is what different happens when writing to
> a pipe: is it not just a block of memory in the kernel somewhere that
> the child can read from?

There's a little more to it than that, but that's a reasonable first approximation.

> In that case, why is it so much faster than
> the basically identical process of writing to a file?

Because writing to a regular file is *not* basically identical.  There's a lot more to it.

Comment: Thanks; maybe I do have some misconceptions.  Let's address them please: For #1, regarding flushing to the file, I was basing my conception off the answer **and final comment** from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10701363) by @James Kanze.  Moreover, if there is a lot more to the difference between a file and pipe, can you point me to something which talks about this?

Comment: @Wad, just as Kanze said, opening the file in synchronous mode would ensure that the data written by *each* `write` are passed on to the device before that `write` call returns.  That does not imply that there is never any delay or kernel-initiated flushing for files not opened in synchronous mode.

Comment: @Wad, requests for off-site resources are off topic here, but I have already presented a high-level view of the main relevant differences.  In particular, there is an actual hardware device with which to interact in the file case, and on top of that a file system that must mediate the access.

Comment: Yes, I get what the linked answer is saying.  But I am not using those flags, and am particularly interested in the _"A return from write() guarantees that the OS has the data, and will "finish up" processing it regardless of what happens to your process_" comment.  If no actual disk activity happens until the kernel buffers are flushed by `pdflush` or similar then I still don't know what `write(FILE)` does that is so much slower than `write(PIPE)`.  Which is exactly what I am asking.

Comment: Moreover, I feel that my request for off site resources if _far_ from "off topic", since many, many answers here have some "off site" resource to back them up.  But thank you for the time you have spent.

Comment: Yes, @Wad, I know you are not using those flags.  The point is that the comment you are pointing to does not support your conclusion about the behavior in your case.  It doesn't speak to your case at all, except that it is fair to conclude that the behavior is *somehow* different there.

Comment: OK, I can agree to that.  I'll probably have to put a bounty on this to get the definitive answer to what `write(FILE)` does that is so much slower than `write(PIPE)`; it might seem pedantic but I don't want to not know.

Comment: The point I suspect you are missing is that you're performing many writes, not just one.  In the pipe case, the sink can drain the pipe fast enough that writes are minimally delayed.  In the file case, with a (kernel) I/O buffer substantially smaller than your aggregate write size, you're throttled to the speed at which the kernel can deliver data to the disk for much of the transfer.