# Guarantees in write ahead logging implementation

Tags: c, algorithm, file-io

If one were to issue a sequential series of `write(2)` in Linux/Unix seperated by `fdatasync(2)` or `fsync(2)` or `sync(2)` is it guaranteed that the first write() will be committed to disk before your second write()? The following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132343/how-does-behave-linux-buffer-cache-when-an-application-is-crashing-down) seems to say that such guarantees cannot be given, since there are multiple caching layers involved. For database systems which guarantee consistency this seems to be important, since in WAL (Write Ahead Logging) recovery, you'd need your logs to be persisted on disk before actually changing your data, so that in the event of an application/system failure you can revert back to your last known consistent state. How is this ensured/implemented in an actual database system?

Comment: I would look at the explanations on the SQLite site. It covers how the approaches used in so much as it provides an overview of when hardware (sync) flushes are used, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sync()` system call is practically no help whatsoever; it promises to schedule the write-to-disk operations, but that's about all.

The normal technique used is to set the correct options when you [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) the file descriptor for the disk file: `O_DSYNC`, `O_RSYNC`, `O_SYNC`.  However, the [`fsync()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fsync.html) and [`fdatasync()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdatasync.html) get pretty close to the same effects.  You can also look at `O_DIRECTIO` which is often supported, though it is not standardized at all by POSIX.

Ultimately, the DBMS relies on the O/S to undertake that data written and synchronized to one disk is secure.  As long as the device will always return what the DBMS last wrote, even if it is not on actual disk yet because of caching (because it is backed up in non-volatile cache, or something like that), then it isn't critical.  If, on the other, you have NAS (network attached storage) that doesn't guarantee that what you last wrote (and were told was safe on disk) is returned when you read it, then your DBMS can suffer if it has to do recovery.  So, you choose where you store your DBMS with care, making sure the storage works sensibly.  If the storage does not work sufficiently like the hypothetical disk, you can end up losing data.

Comment: DirectIO does not provide the guarantees that this question asks. But OSYNC flag to open does the what is expected, sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `fsync` in modern versions of the kernel does both flush memory (buffer cache) to disk and disk hardware buffer to platter. Man page says older kernels used to only do the first thing.

> DESCRIPTION    fsync() transfers ("flushes") all modified in-core data
>   of (i.e., modi‐    fied  buffer cache pages for) the file referred to
>   by the file descrip‐    tor fd to the disk device (or other permanent
>   storage device)  so  that    all  changed information can be retrieved
>   even after the system crashed    or was rebooted.  **This includes
>   writing  through  or  flushing  a  disk    cache  if  present.**   The
>   call blocks until the device reports that the    transfer has
>   completed.  It also flushes metadata  information  associ‐    ated
>   with the file (see stat(2)).
>
> The  fsync()  implementations **in older kernels and lesser used
>   filesys‐    tems does not know how to flush  disk  caches.**   In  these
>   cases  disk    caches  need  to  be disabled using hdparm(8) or
>   sdparm(8) to guarantee    safe operation.

This refers to what applications can request. Fsync is an interface that filesystems provide to applications, filesystems themselves use something else underneath. Filesystems use barriers, or rather explicit flushes and FUA requests to commit the journal. Look at [LWN post.](https://lwn.net/Articles/400541/)