# Safe way to write config file in C

Tags: c, linux

I found a problem when a single process updates the config. Sometimes the config file will be empty. I analysed the log; there is log after open, but not log before fwrite.

So I came to the conclusion that if the process crashes after fopen but before write, bad things happen. I know that fwrite(w) will empty the file first, and then add content to the file, so full disk space and process crash may cause problems.

I am curious if there is a safe way to update the config file in C (it had better be C++98 in using C++; we have a very old project that does not support C++11, 14…).

Here is a simple example I wrote. When `file.txt` has something in it, uncomment the return 0, then `file.txt` will be empty.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main () {
   FILE *fp;
   char str[] = "This is stackoverflow.com";

   fp = fopen( "file.txt" , "w" );
   //print log after fopen
   //if the process killed or exit here,file will be empty
   //return 0;

   //print log before fwrite
   fwrite(str , 1 , sizeof(str) , fp );
   //print log after fwrite
   fclose(fp);

   return(0);

}
```

Comment: Check for errors! You never do.

Comment: The file is emptied when `fopen()` is run.  If you crash between the `fwrite()` and the `fclose()`, it is not guaranteed that the data will be written to file.  You could set the buffering to line buffering and include a newline in the string (and probably write `sizeof(str) - 1` bytes to the file to avoid writing a null byte to the file);  you could use `fflush(fp);`.  If you're writing log files, it is a good idea to include `fflush(fp)` at the end of each complete message.

Comment: If you want robustness, you need to write a second file.  `fsync` it. Then `rename(2)` the new copy.

Answer (score 0):

`fwrite()` is buffered. So what you write is kept in memory in standard I/O buffers.

This indeed means that data can be lost if the program crashes (soon after the write call).

When calling `fflush()`, the I/O buffers are flushed to the OS. It's then the OS' responsibility to make sure the data ends up on disk. When an app crashes after the `fflush()` call, the data will typically still be written to disk.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5132343/1971013) for a bit more info.

As @EugineSh. rightly comments above: You must check the result of each of these C library calls.

To avoid immediately emptying a pre-existing config file, you could use `tmpfile()` C library function to create a temporary new version. Then when it's done, you can copy over the contents into the final config file. Of course you could also cache the config data in memory buffer.

EDIT: Depending on your OS, have a look what you could do with file locks.

Comment: My question is app crashes after fopen(w) before fwrite,It will empty the file.In our project we had called fflush() after fwrite execute immediately.By the way,flush() should be fflush().

Comment: Question: If fwrite returns successful and data is stored in the buffer, but you call fclose right after is the data still written?

Comment: @Nina Yes, `fclose()` makes sure the data is written to file.

Comment: *`fclose()` makes sure the data is written to file*  Only if there aren't any errors.  If you don't check for errors, `fclose()` can fail silently.

Comment: @J.Doe `write("w")` creates a new empty file. So what you're seeing seems standard behavior.

Comment: @meaning-matters This is the problem I encountered. I can't think of a good way to solve it.

Comment: No, fclose does not ensure the data is written to disk. It ensures the data is written from the process' memory space into kernel buffers.  It might not hit the physical device for 10s of seconds, or even minutes.  If you want it on a physical device, you need to `fsync`

Comment: @meaning-matters tmpfile() are useless here,use tmpfile(),you don't generate a file.

Comment: @J.Doe What do you mean, here's a manual page of [tmpfile()](http://man.freetechsecrets.com/tmpfile.3.html) "The tmpfile() function generates a unique temporary filename. The temporary file is then opened in binary read/write (w+b) mode."

Comment: @meaning-matters The tmpfile() function returns a stream descriptor,will not generate a file on disk,there is no way to know the file name,will you give a example ? Have you tried?

Comment: @J.Doe True, but I suggested to use a temporary file or a memory buffer to store your new config data. Then when you know you can save, you open the original and write the contents of that temporary file or memory buffer to it. This keeps the time between opening and closing the original config file as short as possible. (You don't need the `tmp file()`'s name of course to only use it as a buffer: Just `fseek()` to begin and copy contents. It seems that just having a memory buffer might be the simplest as I assume it's very little data.

Answer (score 0):

You can open it with `fopen(a)`, that appends content to the file, and then `rewind` or `fseek` to the first position of the file.

But maybe this solution is worse if you write less than the previous content of the file, because then they will be mixed: The first bytes will be the written, but you will find the previous contents after that. You could `truncate` the file, but then the point of failure is just in other place.

The proper solution is to create another temporary file and swap (override) the original one.